# Does the phrase "fine with me" have a negative connotation?

Tags: connotation, conversation

I have always thought that you could answer "it's ok with me" or "it's fine with me" when you agree with something that somebody proposed, like a meeting time.

But apparently the phrase can have a negative connotation.

According to [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fine%20with%20me) Urban Dictionary it means:

> *I could care less.* Usually used when
>   someone is being overly dramatic and
>   is explaining the extreme action they
>   are planning to do in response to a
>   situation that they think you should
>   care a lot about, but still somehow
>   you don't similar to "that's just fine
>   with me"

Since I wasn't sure if this source was reliable, I googled it and apparently the definition is correct:

"We made our play, and I came out on top. Okay? Now, if you want to start the game up again, that's **fine with me**."
[The Italian Job (film)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317740/quotes)

"I'd never have a hookup but if that's what someone is into, **fine with me**."
[Comment on a blog post](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.datingish.com%2F729462209%2Fconfessions-of-a-makeout-whore%2F&ei=hBBlTObPMouOjAfq1Z3lCw&usg=AFQjCNGuk251Zxu3eJY2tRq0SJ2FJNTVQw&sig2=eyNfB9SJefbMufFx_UO3bA)

Can I be misinterpreted when I say "it's fine with me" meaning that I agree with the proposal? My concern is that it can be understood as "ok, i don't really care."

Comment: Please be advised that _I could care less_ actually should be _I couldn't care less_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It very much depends on the tone of voice with which this is said. It can simply represent a casual way of voicing agreement, but if you're not careful, quite easily apathy.

Comment: Thanks, but what if it is written (e.g. email)?

Comment: If you're casually arranging/deciding on something, it is probably polite enough, but depends on context still. It's very hard even for a native speaker to judge.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. The meaning of "fine with me" can indeed go either way, depending on how you say it and the context.

As a rule though, just saying

> Fine with me.

as an answer to a question without any other niceties surrounding it could often and easily be construed as a bit defensive and aggressive.

My advice would be, if you use it, always "pad it with politeness."

Comment: Defensive *and* aggressive? Wow.

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely in the context you've given that you will be misinterpreted when you say "it's fine with me" meaning that you agree with a proposal.

In your example from the Italian Job, I bet the speaker would be happy to start the game up again.  Probably they think they will come out on top again.  It the second example, I bet the author really doesn't have a problem with other people having a hookup.  So in both cases the speaker isn't necessarily showing opposition or disinterest.